# What does this mean? 8GB or 4GB? which is better?

Tags: laptop

What does this mean?

DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, 8GB, 
On-board Memory 4 GB, 
1 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 12 GB SDRAM

and

1600 MHz DDR3L SDRAM, 4GB
Memory slots    2 SODIMM

which one is better?

Comment: `which one is much more better?`. You don't need the word more. :) Also, better for what?

Comment: Please link to the specs of both laptops! That will make things much clearer. Or upload a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you know we are taking about pc ram, which [allows data items to be accessed (read or written) in almost the same amount of time irrespective of the physical location of data inside the memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory)

In terms of *speed* the specifications are identical, they both work at (and I qoute) `1600MHz`, which means they can be read/written 1,600,000,000 times per second.

In terms of *capacity*, they differ, because the first one **can** be expanded up to 12GB, while the second one has two 4GB slots, hence a maximum capacity of only 8GB.

However, the first specification only has **4GB** installed, you *may*, (if you wish, at extra cost) expand it up to 12GB. The second specification instead *seems* to have its maximum capacity already installed, *i.e.* 8GB; thus, as they stand, the second specification is better.

Just for the record: a SODIMM is a small outline dual in-line memory module, which is smaller than a DIMM. The first specification indicates that its unique SODIMM available for expansion can accommodate an 8GB memory module, as they are available currently, see [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006YG8X9Y) to get an illustration of what they look like.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but the first seems to have 4GB RAM onboard, probably fixed and non-removable. There is one socket for another SO-DIMM memory module, which can be up to 8GB in size, as it says it can be expanded to 12GB.

The 8GB means probably that this is the actual memory in this laptop. That means 4GB onboard, and the second socket has a 4GB module, which can later be replaced with a 8GB module.

> DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, 8GB, On-board Memory 4 GB, 1 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 12 GB SDRAM

The second configuration has 4GB memory, and two slots. Now what does that mean? One 4GB module in one slot, or two 2GB modules in both slots? That last configuration is not likely anymore, but you never know. Then it's unclear what the limit is for those slots. Is it 4GB or 8GB? If it's 8GB, then the total memory could be 16GB, which is better than the first configuration.

> 1600 MHz DDR3L SDRAM, 4 GB Memory slots 2 SODIMM

So in this configuration, 8GB is better than 4GB, so the first seems to be better. If the second laptop can be upgraded to 16GB, that is better in the long run, if you're going to do memory intensive tasks, like video processing. For now, 4GB is the absolute minimum, and 8GB is the new norm. It works with 4GB, but you can run into limitations.

Answer (score 0):

It's Specification for RAM(Memory)

Since you tagged laptop I'm going to assume your looking to buy a laptop and are wondering which one is better.

Without going into nitty gritty details about what each one means I'd recommend the laptop with

> DDR3L 1600 MHz SDRAM, 8GB, On-board Memory 4 GB, 1 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 12 GB SDRAM

It has twice the memory as the latter and will perform a lot faster.

Although there a more things to consider than just memory.
If i'm wrong in my assumption please let me know and I'll remove my answer.